# The Testament of Sherlock Holmes - how to unequip an item?

Tags: the-testament-of-sherlock-holmes

After equipping an item, the icon doesn't disappear from the top right corner of the screen:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find, you can use the scrollwheel to change active items.

Try scrolling and you will possibly reach the empty equipment slot. [Source](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thetestamentofsherlockholmes/guide.asp?ID=17127)